# Idisk Sync - Progress on 4GB Encrypted Volume

Tags: macos, dropbox, mobileme

I'm trying to gauge the progress on a 4gb truecrypt volume I'm putting on my idisk. The progress indicator only has one item and perpetually stays at 0%. Is there any way to know how much of the file I've uploaded?

Is iDisk capable of resuming this upload? I move between the office and because of the size of the file I haven't had a continuous upload session.

DropBox does a much better job of this. Should have just gone with that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox may well have issues with a situation like this too.  Please realize that uploading a 4GB truecrypt volume is the same as uploading any 4GB file regardless of the number of files contained in the volume.  The whole point of trucrypt is to obscure the content of it's volumes - your computer is not aware that it is in actuallity a bung of little files.

If you are at 0% after a long while, you may wish to restart when you will have a connection that will last long enough to upload the entire 4GB.

Comment: My experience with DropBox and a 1GB file was that once it was uploaded it did differential uploads.